# ASPX background image shown in source but not in webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am using VS2005 C#.

I have a login page which uses a background image from the CSS.

After I have modified my *web.config* to cater for AD authentication, the background image does not show anymore.

I am able to see the background image when viewed in *source*, but when the login page is *viewed in browser*, the background is plain white.

Below is the code snippet of my *Login.aspx*, *loginCSS.css* and *Web.config*:

Login.aspx:

---

```
<head runat="server"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="loginCSS.css" />
    <title>Login</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div  align="center">
    <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" BackColor="#F7F6F3" BorderColor="#E6E2D8" 
            BorderPadding="4" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" 
            Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#333333" Height="130px" 
            Width="303px">
          <TextBoxStyle Font-Size="Small" />
          <LoginButtonStyle BackColor="#FFFBFF" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" 
              BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#284775" />
          <InstructionTextStyle Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Black" />
          <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" 
              ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:Login>

</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

LoginCSS.css

---

```
body 
{
    background-image:url('images/loginbackground.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

---

Web.config:

---

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" timeout="10" loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Common/Default.aspx">
            </forms>
        </authentication>
```

---

May I know what went wrong? Is there a better way to display a background image in my login form?

Comment: is the css being loaded, check in firebug or ie web develop tool bars, show where you background image is actually set for us as well

Comment: @DanielPowell my background image is set inside my CSS file. I will add in my CSS file too

Comment: if you broswe to the css file directly in your browser what happens

Comment: @RUiHAO - Did you set authorization to anonymous user in web.config? If yes then use location element to allow access of images folder for anonymous user.

Comment: when i browse to the css file directly via the url, it redirected me back to the login page `/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fSoD%2flogincss.css`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you might be requiring authentication for your CSS or image files.

Try adding

```
<location path="images">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

<location path="loginCss.css">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

which would give you anyone permission to retrieve your css/images without having to login